# iPhone8 vibrates in response to some interface - how to disable?

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility

I have an iPhone 8 for testing iOS apps. It has some weird feedback feature, where the phone vibrates mildly in response to actions, like flipping on/off switches in the settings app. It feels similar to when I press the fake home button.

**How do I disable "vibrate in response" to interface on iPhone8?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn them off in Preferences -> Sound and Haptics -> System Haptic feedback.

Note: I’m not sure about the English labels for those menus. Please edit an answer if I’m wrong.